# Colocar elementos em listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Gostaria de ter duas listas: uma com o nome das frutas e outra com as cores.

```
lista = ['banana [amarela]\n', 'uva [vinho]\n', 'laranja [laranjado]\n', 'kiwi [verde]\n', 'framboesa [vermelho]\n', 'coco [marrom]\n']

lines = lista.split(" ")

fruits = []
colors = []

for line in lines:
    fruits.append(line[0])
    #colors.append(line[1]) #IndexError: string index out of range

print(fruits)
#print(colors) #IndexError: string index out of range
```

Saída do script:

> ['[', "'", 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', ' ', '[', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'l', 'a', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'u', 'v', 'a', ' ', '[', 'v', 'i', 'n', 'h', 'o', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'l', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'j', 'a', ' ', '[', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'j', 'a', 'd', 'o', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'k', 'i', 'w', 'i', ' ', '[', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'd', 'e', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'f', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'b', 'o', 'e', 's', 'a', ' ', '[', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'm', 'e', 'l', 'h', 'o', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o', ' ', '[', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'o', 'm', ']', '\', 'n', "'", ']']

Saída desejada:

> fruits = ['banana', 'uva', 'laranja', 'kiwi', 'framboesa', 'coco']
>
> colors = ['amarela', 'vinho', 'laranjado', 'verde', 'vermelho', 'marrom']

Comment: Esses valores estão em um arquivo? Você está usando ali as funções `read` e `readlines` que parecem ser de um arquivo texto.

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe. Eu estou usando estes valores em um arquivo, mas achei que seria mais fácil colocar a lista aqui. Vou editar a minha resposta.

Comment: Mas em que formato está cada linha do arquivo ? Existe sempre apenas uma fruta e uma cor por linha ?

Comment: Fica mais fácil, de fato, só quis me certificar se não estava usando as funções de maneira inadequada para ler os valores de uma lista.

Comment: Isac, exatamente. Uma fruta e uma cor por linha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quebrar o conteúdo do texto no espaço em branco não parece ser uma boa solução, visto que que podem existir nomes de frutas e cores que possuem espaços, como por exemplo `fruta do conde [rosa choque]` (*joga fora, está podre!*), ou algo do gênero. Se o padrão sempre for `fruta [cor]`, acredito que seja mais viável utilizar uma expressão regular:

```
(.+) \[(.+)\]\n?
```

1. `(.+)` cria um grupo de captura para qualquer sequência de caracteres;
2. Espaço em branco, indicando que o grupo anterior necessariamente deve ser seguido de um espaço;
3. `\[(.+)\]` cria outro grupo de captura para qualquer sequência de caracteres entre colchetes;
4. `\n?` define que a linha pode, ou não, terminar em um caractere `\n`;

Desta forma, o nome da fruta casará com qualquer sequência de caracteres, desde que seguido de um espaço em branco e uma outra sequência qualquer de caracteres entre colchetes, podendo ou não ser terminada com o caractere `\n`. O primeiro grupo será o nome da fruta e o segundo grupo será sua cor. Em Python ficaria:

```
import re

lista = ['banana [amarela]\n', 'uva [vinho]\n', 'laranja [laranjado]\n', 'kiwi [verde]\n', 'framboesa [vermelho]\n', 'coco [marrom]\n']

pattern = re.compile(r"(.+) \[(.+)\]\n?")

frutas = []
cores = []

for item in lista:
    if pattern.match(item):
        fruta, cor = pattern.search(item).groups()
        frutas.append(fruta)
        cores.append(cor)

print(frutas)
print(cores)
```

Produzindo o resultado:

```
['banana', 'uva', 'laranja', 'kiwi', 'framboesa', 'coco']
['amarela', 'vinho', 'laranjado', 'verde', 'vermelho', 'marrom']
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nhTg7Y).

O a função `re.compile` irá gerar uma estrutura em Python para tratar da expressão regular supracitada. Então, é percorrida a lista de itens e, com o método `pattern.match`, verifica se o conteúdo do item é compatível com o padrão esperado e, se for, extrai os valores dos grupos de captura através do método `pattern.search`. O método `groups` irá retornar uma tupla com os valores dos grupos de captura, nesse caso uma tupla de dois valores: o nome da fruta e a respectiva cor. Assim, é utilizado a técnica de *unpacking* dos valores das tuplas em duas variáveis:

```
fruta, cor = ("banana", "amarela")
```

Fazendo com que `fruta` receba `banana` e `cor` receba `amarela`, armazenando os valores nas respectivas listas.

Se estes valores estão armazenados em um arquivo texto, pode fazer assim:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(.+) \[(.+)\]\n?")

frutas = []
cores = []

with open("lista.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if pattern.match(line):
            fruta, cor = pattern.search(line).groups()
            frutas.append(fruta)
            cores.append(cor)

print(frutas)
print(cores)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LC1f/2).

Answer (score 1):

Se for tão constante como apresentado no teu exemplo podes fazer:

```
lista = ['banana [amarela]\n', 'uva [vinho]\n', 'laranja [laranjado]\n', 'kiwi [verde]\n', 'framboesa [vermelho]\n', 'coco [marrom]\n']
colors = []
fruits = []
for ele in lista:
    fruit, color = ele.strip().split(' ')
    colors.append(color[1:-1]) # retirar parentesis retos da cor
    fruits.append(fruit)

print(fruits) # ['banana', 'uva', 'laranja', 'kiwi', 'framboesa', 'coco']
print(colors) # ['amarela', 'vinho', 'laranjado', 'verde', 'vermelho', 'marrom']
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/LC1D)

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
lista = ['banana [amarela]\n', 'uva [vinho]\n', 'laranja [laranjado]\n', 'kiwi [verde]\n', 'framboesa [vermelho]\n', 'coco [marrom]\n']

fruits, color = []

for element in lista:
    fc = element.split(" ")
    fruits += [fc[0]]
    color += [fc[1][1:-3]]

print "lista de frutas =" + str(fruits)
print "lista de cores =" + str(color)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lista = ['banana [amarela]\n', 'uva [vinho]\n', 'laranja [laranjado]\n', 'kiwi [verde]\n', 'framboesa [vermelho]\n', 'coco [marrom]\n']
>>> l1, l2 = zip(*(l.strip().replace('[','').replace(']','').split() for l in lista))
>>> l1
('banana', 'uva', 'laranja', 'kiwi', 'framboesa', 'coco')
>>> l2
('amarela', 'vinho', 'laranjado', 'verde', 'vermelho', 'marrom')
```

Ou se precisa de lista

```
>>> list(l1)
['banana', 'uva', 'laranja', 'kiwi', 'framboesa', 'coco']
>>> list(l2)
['amarela', 'vinho', 'laranjado', 'verde', 'vermelho', 'marrom']
```